# Consul: proxy.inbound: failed to dial: error="dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused"

Tags: docker, consul

I'm trying to connect an app running on an ec2 instance in a docker container to a database service on another instance with Consul connect. The services are registering and visible in the UI, all nodes and services are visible with `consul members` and `consul catalog services` (including the side car proxy services), and I can use `curl database.service.consul:8500 --resolve database.service.consul:8500:127.0.0.1` on the frontend instance to see the Consul Agent is running on the database instance

The problem is when I try and use Consul Connect I get either:

`dial tcp 127.0.0.1:21000: connect: connection refused` in the Consul UI "Connect Sidecar Listening" check

or

`[ERROR] proxy.inbound: failed to dial: error="dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused"` when I use the command line.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425051/consul-proxy-failed-to-dial-dial-tcp-127-0-0-10-connect-connection-refused) that looks superficially the same but they weren't assigning a port in the service definition which I already am assigning so I don't think that's my direct issue. Additionaly, the security group allows all required ports through.

Service definitions:

Frontend:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "frontend",
    "port": 80,
    "connect": {
      "sidecar_service": {
        "proxy": {
          "upstreams": [
            {
              "destination_name": "database",
              "local_bind_port": 5432
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Database:

```
{
  "service": {
    "name": "database",
    "port": 5432,
    "connect": { "sidecar_service": {} }
  }
}
```

Starting the consul agents:

```
PRIVATE_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)

consul agent \
    -data-dir=/opt/consul/ \
    -config-dir=/opt/consul \
    -client=0.0.0.0 \
    -advertise=$PRIVATE_IP \
    -retry-join="provider=aws tag_key=Name tag_value=consul_server" \
    -enable-local-script-checks \
    -https-port=8501 \
    -grpc-port=8502

consul connect proxy -sidecar-for frontend
```

From there I'm just starting the docker container with `-p 80:80`

Comment: Update: can get the services connected but only if I run the `consul agent` command then start a separate terminal session and run the `consul connect proxy`. Maybe a matter of timing and the agent needs a bit more time to start?

Comment: Yes, it is probably just a matter of timing. The agent needs to start and join the cluster before it will be able to handle requests from the sidecar proxy. You should start the agent using systemd and use the following unit file https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/deployment-guide#configure-systemd. `Type=notify` will cause systemd to wait for Consul to confirm that it started (i.e., joined the cluster) before starting dependent processes, such as Envoy. You'll need to create this dependency by specifying a directive like `Wants=` in Envoy's systemd unit.